# using mapdata to highlight specific countries

Tags: r

I am generating a world map and hoping to highlight some specific countries. This is my attempt:

```
require(mapdata)
cc <- map('world', names = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
take <- unlist(sapply(c("uk", "usa", "switzerland","new zealand",
                        "israel","denmark","sweden","italy",'canada'),
                      grep, tolower(cc), value = TRUE))
map()
map('world', regions=take, fill=TRUE, col='red', add = TRUE)

nums <- c(12,11,1,2,1,1,1,1,1)
```

[image]

I have two questions.

1) Is it possible to include points on this map to correspond to the variable 'nums'. Each of the numbers in 'nums' refers to the number of measurements taken from a specific country, 12 is for the UK and so on... Is it possible to include a point on the map with the radius of that point corresponding to the number in 'nums'. I know this is possible with ggplot2 but am not sure how to do it with mapdata?

2) How can I make this map look nicer i.e. there seem to be a lot of empty countries here, is there an elegant way of only including the countries that are colored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm something like this?

```
require(mapdata)
cc <- map('world', names = TRUE, plot = FALSE)
take <- unlist(sapply(countries <- c("uk", "usa", "switzerland","new zealand",
                        "israel","denmark","sweden","italy",'canada'),
                      grep, tolower(cc), value = TRUE))
nums <- c(12,11,1,2,1,1,1,1,1)
# gc <- ggmap::geocode(countries) # a googlemaps query gives this: 
gc <- structure(list(lon = 
c(-3.435973, -95.712891, 8.227512, 174.885971, 
34.851612, 9.501785, 18.643501, 12.56738, -106.346771), lat = c(55.378051, 
37.09024, 46.818188, -40.900557, 31.046051, 56.26392, 60.128161, 
41.87194, 56.130366)), 
.Names = c("lon", "lat"), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -9L))

map(xlim=c(-150, 40), ylim=c(25, 75)) # plot only a part of the world map
map('world', regions=take, fill=TRUE, col='red', add = TRUE, )
with(gc, points(lon, lat, cex=nums, pch=19, col=rgb(0, 1, 0, .8))) # add circles
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using `sqrt(nums)` instead, since the eye tends to infer the relative comparison with area vice radius (i.e., as is, the larger numbers are being exaggerated). Also, can use `symbols` vice `points`; not critical in this application but if the radius needs to use the same units as the rest of the plot then `pch`/`cex` doesn't work well.